# save and retrieve variable values from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

**what i am trying to accomplish:**

Program looks for the file and if file exists then load the variable value from the file to and integer variable and then add 1 (variable + 1) and then write to the file again by replacing the existing value

And if the file does not exist then create the file and write variable value into the file

**here is my attempt by looking at the examples provided by other programmer on this site**

```
import pickle
import os


PATH = './file.p'

if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
    print("file is available to read")
    var1 = pickle.load(open("file.p","rb"))
    print(var1)

    pickle.dump([var1+1], open("file.p", "wb"))
    print ("var+1 is added to the file")

else:
    var1=0;
    pickle.dump([var1], open("file.p", "wb"))

    print("file is created and var1 added to the file")
```

there seems to be something wrong with the code, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed your code by changing the write value of var to int, not list (your convert it to a list because of the[]). Here's the new code:

```
import pickle
import os


PATH = './file.p'

if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
    print("file is available to read")
    var1 = pickle.load(open("file.p","rb"))
    print(var1)
    var0 = var1+1
    pickle.dump(var0, open("file.p", "wb"))

    print ("var+1 is added to the file")

else:
    var1=0
    pickle.dump(var1, open("file.p", "wb"))

    print("file is created and var1 added to the file")
```

Hope it helps, good luck

Comment: works like a charm , thanks for telling me what i was doing wrong